# Virtual keyword in multiple layer inheritance

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an inheritance chain, where class A publicly inherits from class B, which in turn publicly inherits from class C. The destructor of class C is marked as "virtual". Is there any objection against marking the destructors of class B and A as virtual? Or is there a performance/memory penalty to pay in these situations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the base class destructor is marked virtual then the Derived class destructor is implicitly virtual as well, you don't need to specify it as virtual explicitly.
There's no *performance or memory* penalty

So in your example, if `C` has a virtual destructor `B` and `A` inherits the "virtual-ness" of destructor

Comment: I know I don't need to do it, but if I did specify A and B's destructors as virtual, would that cause a penalty? I mean, if I added the keyword just for clarity that these are virtual functions.

Comment: @Frank yeah that fine as well.

Comment: @Frank no difference. A and B dtors are already virtual if C dtor is virtual, whether you use *virtual* keyword for A and B dtors explicitly or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. The compiler creates and manages a vtable for such a hierarchy as soon as there is at least one virtual member function (special or ordinary).

However, as the following situation is a route to UB

```
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

Base *b = new Derived{};

delete b; /* Undefined behavior, destructor of B is not virtual. */
```

it is a common automatism to change the above Base class to

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

and now any derived class can safely be deleted through the *virtual* destructor of `B`.

There are situations though in which an inheritance hierarchy is supposed to extend class functionality without use cases with references to a Base instance. Then, you should go with a *protected, non-virtual* destructor. The base class can hence only be destroyed from within derived classes:

```
class Base {
  protected:
    ~Base() = default;
};
```

disallows this snippet

```
Base *b = new Derived{};

delete b; /* Error, ~Base() is protected. */
```

but allows for

```
Derived *d = new Derived{};

delete d; /* That's fine.*/
```

and hence saves the class usage from undefined behavior while the compiler won't generate a vtable for you, allowing for maximum performance. This is a common technique e.g. in policy based design.